# Querying Nested List Existence in Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

I have a document in Mongo that is structured in the following way:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4eea7237d0ba3a04f20008fb"), 
    "code" : "b2677c2809c844cc9d7e3e4ff8d95b46", 
    "city_id" : 4, 
    "datetime" : ISODate("2011-12-13T18:41:44.062Z"), 
    "plays" : [     
        {   
          "play_id" : 717224,   
          "clicks" : [ ],   
          "order" : 1,  
          "mysql_id" : 145
        }
```

I want to query for docs whose plays.clicks attribute is a non-empty list.  I've tried exists with no luck.  I thought that something like this might work:

```
 db.collection.find({plays.clicks.0: {$exists:true}})
```

But I believe that this would return only docs whose first element in the plays array contains a non-empty clicks list.

Any thought on how I might get this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`db.collection.find({plays.clicks.0: {$exists:true}})`

is the right syntax, however as `plays` is a list the query will match *any document* that has clicks in `plays`.  There is no way to retrieve a subset of an Array for subelements in this way[1].  There is a ticket for sub / virtual collections[2]

[1] http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements

[2] https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828

Comment: Thanks Ross, this is probably the best answer (though the additional denormalization proposal is a reasonable alternative).

Answer (score 3):

Save the size of the list as a separate attribute (e.g. `num_plays`). Then you can query for documents where `num_plays` is greater than `0`:

Comment: I could do this.  From a reading standpoint, this probably allows for the fastest queries.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but I think the query you want is

```
{ "plays.clicks" : { "$size" : 0 } }
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24size

Comment: Yeah, that would be fine if I wanted to return all docs where the list size was 0.  Unfortunately, I want the inverse and that doesn't seem possible.