# Return Every Certain Object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

How to write a query which returns "every" object in the NoSQL database named "address"? ... please note it may be "nested" to other objects.

I tried

```js
.find({
  'result.extractorData.data[0].group[0].address': {
    $exists: true
  }
});
```

But that didn't work, BTW Data Looks Like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think for nested arrays you better to use elemMatch operator

See similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505816/mongodb-object-property-exists-in-nested-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583179/querying-nested-list-existence-in-mongo)

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

More on [elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Also another way you can:

```
.find({
  'result.extractorData.data.group.address': {
    $exists: true
  }
});
```

Comment: any examples please?

Comment: @Microsmsm Can you list example of the output that you expect?